# How to fix expression must have a constant value in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to write a program that hashes a string to use it in a switch and when I call the hash function I get the error : `expression must have a constant value`

The code in question is:

```
unsigned int hashString(const std::string string_input, int hash_seed)
{
  {
    return !string_input[0] 
    ? 33129 : (hashString(string_input, 1) 
    * 54) ^ string_input[0];
  }
}




bool evaluateString(std::string str)
{
  string first_word;
  stringstream inputStream { str };

    commandStream >> first_word;

    switch (hashString(first_word, 0))
    {
    case hashString(ipo::Io::STRING_HELLO, 0):
      /* code */
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }


}
```

The error occurs here: `case hashString(ipo::Io::STRING_HELLO, 0):`

It marks the `ipo` as a problem

How could I fix it

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is `ipo::Io::STRING_HELLO`?

Comment: Hard to test that because you didn't provide a [minimal reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but declaring the first function as `constexpr` should help.

Comment: The problem is with the switch statement. You cannot have non-constant expression as the cases.

Comment: Decide if you want to use c++11, c++14 or c++17 and please remove unnecessary tags.

Comment: Your function should become constexpr, causing std::string to be replaced by `std::string_view`

Comment: You cannot have the non-constexpr value as a `case` parameter. Unfortunately your `hashString` function is not easily convertible to `constexpr`, because you have recurrent call inside.

Comment: _How could I fix it_? Use an if-else block

Comment: @pptaszni: recursive constexpr function is fine (and required in C++11). Issue is that function is broken with infinite recursion...

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
constexpr unsigned int hashString(const std::string_view s, int hash_seed = 33129)
{
    unsigned int res = hash_seed;
    for (auto rit = s.rbegin(); rit != s.rend(); ++rit) {
        res = (res * 54) ^ *rit;
    }
    return res;
}
```

And then

```
bool evaluateString(const std::string& str)
{
    std::stringstream commandStream{str};

    std::string first_word;
    commandStream >> first_word;

    switch (hashString(first_word))
    {
    case hashString(ipo::Io::STRING_HELLO): // STRING_HELLO should be a constexpr string_view
      /* code */
      break;

    default:
      break;
    }
}
```